# How do I get the Java StyleSheet class to take precedence over external CSS style sheets in Java 7?

Tags: java, html, css

I am trying to use an external CSS style sheet to have default tag properties for a web page I'm displaying in a JEditorPane.  I'm trying to use Java's StyleSheet class to override particular tag properties defined in the external style sheet that my web page is linking to.  I'm using the following code:

```
    editorPane = new JEditorPane();
    editorPane.setEditable(false);
    editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
    try
    {
        editorPane.setPage(new URL("file:///c:/users/ryan/desktop/htmlviewer.htm"));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HTMLEditorKit editorKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
    editorPane.setEditorKit(editorKit);
    HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument) editorKit.createDefaultDocument();

    StyleSheet styleSheet = document.getStyleSheet();
    styleSheet.addRule("p { color:#0000ff; }");

    editorKit.setStyleSheet(styleSheet);

    add(editorPane);
```

My external CSS style sheet contains the line:

p { color:#ff0000; }

When I run this in Java 6, the text color for p tags is #0000ff.  But when I run it in Java 7, the text color for p tags is #ff0000.

Why did the behavior change?  Is there a way I can make the CSS properties I define in Java to take precedence over the ones defined in my external CSS style sheet?  Example code would be appreciated.